# Convert all Non NA values in column name starting with "string" to 1 & NA to 0

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'll use to iris for reproduciblity

```
df <- iris %>% 
      mutate(Species2=Species) %>% 
      map_df(., function(x) {x[sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), size = length(x), replace = TRUE)]}) %>% 
      mutate(across(where(starts_with("Species")),as.factor))
```

I have created another column Species2 & randomly entered NA, what I want to do is convert all non NA values in two columns (Species & Species 2) to 1 & NA's in those two columns to 0

I thought of using across & as .numeric for this, somehow it doesn't work though.

```
 df %>% mutate(across(where(starts_with("Species")),as.numeric))
```

Comment: Since its to be done only for column starting with "Species", can there be a better way. I have used iris for reproduciblility but there are many columns (starting with Species)

Comment: You should remove `where` in `across` since you are selecting the columns based on name. As it stands, your current example gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Species"), ~as.integer(!is.na(.))))
```

In base R, this can be done as :

```
cols <- grep('^Species', names(df))
df[cols] <- +(!is.na(df[cols]))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, next I sum them into a total column, I do this 
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Species"), ~as.integer(!is.na(.)))) %>% 
  mutate(total=across(starts_with("Species"),sum)), gives a wrong output any idea why

Comment: Use : `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Species"), ~as.integer(!is.na(.))),  sum = rowSums(select(., starts_with('Species'))))`

Comment: Yup this works, Any idea why my code in the comment gives wrong output

Comment: `across` is suppose to work column-wise. You are telling it to sum 2 columns and store it in one column `total` which is why it returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

how about using

```
df_NA<-which(df==NA)
df_Val<-which(df>=0)
df[df_NA]<-0
df[df_Val]<-1
```