# change where numbers exist to 1

Tags: r

In a data structure with many columns:

```
data.frame(ad = c(1,2,3,4), col = c(2.2,0,1,4.24,0.2), name = c(0,0.2,3.2,0))
```

What is the most suitable command to see in the 2 column if a cell has a number and change where every there is a number to 1.

Example for result:

```
data.frame(ad = c(1,2,3,4), col = c(1,1,1,1), name = c(0,1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you mean with *if a cell has a number* a number > 0:

```
x[-1][x[-1] > 0] <- 1
x
#  ad col name
#1  1   1    0
#2  2   1    1
#3  3   1    1
#4  4   1    0
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(ad = c(1,2,3,4), col = c(2.2,1,4.24,0.2), name = c(0,0.2,3.2,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can find all values greater than a threshold by multiple means

```
df<-data.frame(ad = c(1,2,3,4,5), col = c(2.2,0,1,4.24,0.2), name = c(0,0.2,3.2,0,4))
```

be aware the data.frame you posted doesn't work so i modified this one a bit

```
1)
df_with_numbers<-which(df>0)
df[df_with_numbers]<-1
df

2) 
df<-ifelse(df$col>0, 1, 0)
```

both should do what you want and there are even more elgant solutions provided by @ronak shah here: [Convert all Non NA values in column name starting with "string" to 1 & NA to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702284/convert-all-non-na-values-in-column-name-starting-with-string-to-1-na-to-0/63702358#63702358)